# Url fragment and Referer header

Tags: http, cross-browser, http-referer, fragment-identifier, fragment

Imagine you are on a page whose URL has a fragment (the part after the `#`), and click a link to go to another page. Most browsers will send the URL of the original page to the server in the `Referer` header. What I want to know is whether or not the URL fragment will be included in this or not.

I have seen various behaviors in the wild so this might be browser-specific. Does anyone know which browsers do what? And what does the HTTP spec say on this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The spec says that Referer can't include a fragment identifier (per ABNF). See [RFC 2616, Section 14.36](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.14.36).

Comment: Does that bear out in practice though? I'm pretty sure I've seen at least some browsers include it.

Comment: That would be interesting; if you can reproduce it please follow up on the IETF HTTPbis WG's mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the same behavior in IE today.
I am using IE 11.0.9600.17801 and upon inspection i found out that the 'Referer' header contains this fragment identifier.

Referer: //abc:8080/myapp/ver/index.htm#search-basics

Although I am quite certain that I have seen this behavior on and off with the same browser.

Answer (score 0):

The spec says basicly that you can do whatever you want - it is an optional header, i just tested webkit ignores the fragment, as do firefox and IE.