# Pound sign in url

Tags: http, url, fragment, http-referer, rfc

When I open a url like `http://stackoverflow.com/#abc`, and then click a link in the page. I find the Referer is still `http://stackoverflow.com` (Chrome, F12). Why not `#abc`?

The same problem appears when I open a redirected url which also includes '#'.

Someone can explain that ? Is there any related RFC document ?

Thank you!

Comment: This was already covered by this [previous Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929897/url-fragment-and-referer-header) Some browsers do include fragments in the referer string, you certainly can't rely on it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's the why the "referer" header field is specified to work? (see http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#header.referer)